# Finding ONLY the mobile device / model name using HTTP_USER_AGENT / Mobile-Detect

Tags: php

I did some research and seem like the server variable HTTP_USER_AGENT can be used to detect the browser type, device name, os etc, however it is not exactly what I want.

I want to call a function which returns **ONLY** the name/model of the device, no browser type, no OS type.

ie if I'm using iPhone 7 it returns iPhone (it will be great if it can tell which iPhone), if I'm using Samsung galaxy I'll get SM-G920V, just like tapatalk signature "Sent from my SM-G920V using Tapatalk"

Comment: My advise: Code a function that extracts the info you want from HTTP_USER_AGENT and ask if you run into problems with existing code.

Comment: But be aware that the info from HTTP_USER_AGENT can very easily be faked, so don't trust that info.

Comment: @Jeff the thing is there are so many different combination of useragent, how am I going to extract from the server variable? I thought that if I call HTTP_USER_AGENT, inside the first bracket the 3rd part (after semi-colon) is the build number but it's not always true

Comment: a `preg_match` would be one way to go!

Comment: can you give me an example of how to grab the device name / model only? again there are too many user agents combinations, I just can't figure out how to do it